# Changing admin in Google Fabric

Tags: google-fabric

All the admins of the Fabric account that we use in my organization have left. Now I need to change the admin to someone who is currently with the organization. What is the procedure to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. You will need to contact support to follow our established flow for this case. We will get you back up and running :)